# Icon is not floating right, the furthest I can get it is central

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap and have some scripts to hide the icon when it is not meant to be displayed. I am making an assumption that this is the cause of the icon not going to the right.

This is what is happening:

[image: Icon not floating right]

This is the code I have in HTML:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title" id="zone_header"></h5>
  <span id="dilemmaZoneIcon" class="icon_hide_dilemmazone dz-icon ml-auto">
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
  </span>
```

The furthest I can get the icon is using `ml-auto` anything else seems to just stick the icon to the last word.

The scripts used to hide the header are to remove or add the class icon_hide_dilemmazone such as:

```
document.getElementById("dilemmaZoneIcon").classList.add("icon_hide_dilemmazone");
```

Any solutions greatly appreciated. I have tried everything from inline styles to !important CSS tags!

Comment: just a side comment: but you do realize that `i` is not `icon`, right? and please post a snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: Oh, it's a fontawesome icon, but yes, I know i is not an icon.

Comment: It's not my CSS, it's all Bootstrap controlled. If you know Bootstrap (which I am a beginner) then you probably know the CSS that is being controlled here.

Comment: did you try adding class="float-right" to the 'dilemmaZoneIcon' element?

Comment: Thanks. I did. I tried it in the class, in CSS and with !important but neither was able to cause the icon to float to the right.